# Converting XML/XSL to HTML file using PHP script in NetBeans

Tags: php, html, xml, xslt, netbeans

I'm trying to convert XML data with an XSL style-sheet to an HTML output, I'm using a simple PHP script to do it, although I'm having trouble to make an actual HTML output, I want to run the script through the Ubuntu terminal that will then generate an HTML file.

By navigating to where the script is i try to run this command to do it but it just generates a blank HTML file

```
XMLtoHTML.php -> test.html
```

Script:

```
<?php

// Load the XML source
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('test.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('test.xsl');

// Configure the transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); // attach the xsl rules

echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I just realized that the problem may just be due to using `->` for the output redirection instead of `>`.

The below answer is still valid, and to get there just issue:

```
XMLtoHTML.php > xsellco.html
```

---

In case you're still wondering, your PHP converter is just fine.

The blank output is probably due to something the XSL/XML files.

Here are sample files that work with the PHP translator you wrote:

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Hello>, world</Hello>
```

**test.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="Hello">
<html>
    <body>
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/><xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Not off the top of my head, so I can only offer you to go back to basics: comment out everything you can, get to the point where something starts to show up, and then start uncommenting code again. Works every time :)